# Logstash can`t handle all input plugins

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I use Logstash input http_handler to collect metrics from different endpoints.
For each endpoint I have separate config file with "input" plugin like:

```
input { http_poller {urls => { server_1 => { url => 'http://10.200.3.1:8809/metrics' } } request_timeout => 5 tags => 'TL.QA.proxy-service' interval => 60 metadata_target => 'http_poller_metadata' type => 'tl_qa_http_metrics'}}
```

I have ~1000 such files in one directory.
When I start Logstash I specify directory to read all those files, like:

```
./bin/logstash -f /opt/logstash-5.6.2/configs/
```

When I had small amount of files (~100) it works pretty good. But now looks like Logstash doesn't have enough time to read all files and it doesn't collect data from all endpoints.
Can you please advise how I can improve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "Logstash doesn't have enough time to read all files"?

Comment: Can you post any error messages in *logstash-plain.log*?

Comment: Instead of 1,000 different input{} blocks, have you tried feeding 1,000 different urls to http_poller{}?  The `urls` parameter takes a hash.